# Component shifting when screen size decreases

Tags: javascript, css

When the screen size is greater than `560px`, my page looks like...

[image]

When the screen size is smaller than `560px`, my page looks like...

[image]

However, when block 2 and block 3 become too close, it looks like...

[image]

when I want it to look like...

[image]

Long story short, block 1 and 3 have set heights and widths, and block 2 doesn't. Instead of block 3 moving down below the level of block 2, I want block 2 to adjust with the screen size. My code (let me know if it's not enough) can be seen below.

```
<div className='box'>
   <div className='test'>
      <p className='box1'>1</p>
   </div>
   <div className='test'>
      <p className='box2'>2</p>
   </div>
   <div className='test'>
      <p className='box3'>3</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  column-gap: 16px;

  div.test {

    &:first-child {
      width: 32px;
      height: 32px;
    }
    &:last-child {
      width: 24px;
      height: 24px;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 560px) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    div.test {

      &:first-child {
        text-align: -webkit-center;
        margin: auto;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
}

p.box1 {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  font-size: 20px;
  object-fit: contain;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-self: center;
}

p.box2 {
  margin: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #000;
}

p.box3 {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  object-fit: contain;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-self: center;
}
```

I changed the code around to try and make it more understandable, but let me know if you have any questions! I think the `flex-wrap: wrap` may be the reason for my issue, but I really don't know how to resolve it without messing up other aspects. I am fairly knew to JS and CSS, so I know I probably have several issues otherwise, but I appreciate any help!

Edit: My styling files are SCSS files.

Comment: I recommend looking into MUI Grid, which creates functionality that handles this exact need.  This can be done on your own, but it would be reinvented sort of complex code that libraries like MYU grid, and others, already did  https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#BasicGrid.js

Comment: @NicholasAponte I appreciate the insight! I will look into it. I'm hoping to find a solution that doesn't cause too much of a headache to fix, but I'm not sure if that'll be possible at this point

Comment: I definitely think the easiest method would be grid. I've tried to do similar responsive pages using plain css, and while doable, its definitely not as simple as it seems

Comment: yeah I got grid to work. Thank you!